# How to set array entries to zero in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an array

```
A = [[1, 2, 4, 0, -2, 6], 
[3, 5, 4, 9, 10, -3], 
[4, 6, 0, -5, 11, 2], 
[0, -3, -4, 0, 12, 8]]
```

and I want to create another array by setting half of A entries to zero i.e.

```
B =  [[1, 2, 4, 0, -0, 0], 
[3, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0], 
[4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, -3, -4, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: What did you attempt?

Comment: Also: Be specific, which elements you want to set to zero. Random elements? Half of the columns?  Always the right half? What if your array has five columns?

Comment: How is the Tensorflow tag related to this exactly?

Comment: Random elements along the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 4, 0, -2, 6], 
              [3, 5, 4, 9, 10, -3], 
              [4, 6, 0, -5, 11, 2], 
              [0, -3, -4, 0, 12, 8]])
a[:, a.shape[1]//2:] = 0
print(a)
```

gives

```
array([[ 1,  2,  4,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  5,  4,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  6,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, -3, -4,  0,  0,  0]])
```

To convert back to a python list, use `a.tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

> One line solution:

```
A = [[1, 2, 4, 0, -2, 6],
[3, 5, 4, 9, 10, -3],
[4, 6, 0, -5, 11, 2],
[0, -3, -4, 0, 12, 8]]



[item.__setitem__(item.index(value), 0)for item in A for index,value in enumerate(item[len(item)//2:])]

print(A)
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0], [3, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0], [4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, -3, -4, 0, 0, 0]]
```

> Detailed solution:

Above list comprehension is same as:

```
for item in A:
    for index,value in enumerate(item[len(item)//2:]):
        item[item.index(value)]=0

print(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension

```
[[0 if i>=len(l)/2 else j for i,j in enumerate(l)] for l in A]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0],
 [3, 5, 4, 0, 0, 0],
 [4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, -3, -4, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution assuming all the rows are of the same length

```
c = len(a[0])
[row[:c/2] + [0] * (c/2) for row in a]
```